# Search for communities in Google+ API

Tags: google-plus

I couldn't find any equivalent to [Google+ API People Search](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/search) for communities. I can retrieve posts from a community only if I have the community ID. I won't ask my user to found by their own the community ID (21 digits ><).

Is there a way to find communities by searching some words? Like in the Google+ search bar (Communities appear in the bottom in the "Communities" section)

Comment: Would you please give details on how you retrieve posts using community ID?

Comment: @therealklanni I was using the same call than for retrieving post of an user (using the community id instead of the user id). But it seems it have been disabled a few weeks ago... ([Issue639](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=639))

Answer (score 2):

Currently, there is no official API support for Google+ Communities. The nature of a Community does mean that some API calls might work right now, but this is unsupported and not guaranteed. Unfortunately, this means that there is no People Search equivalent for Communities at this time.

You can feel free to log this feature request in our Issue Tracker, or to Star the following issue for Community support for email updates on a Communities API in general.
https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=519

Comment: Joanna, has there been any progress on this?